# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - impossible to read url content in php Loop

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to find specific element from the pages below:

```
$links=array(
"https://www.computers.com/l_bg/?m=7&i=587609", 
"https://www.computers.com/l_bg/?m=7&i=587610", 
"https://www.computers.com/l_bg/?m=7&i=587607", 
"https://www.computers.com/l_bg/?m=7&i=587502"
); 


foreach($links as $link){
$newhtml = new simple_html_dom();
$newhtml->load_file($link);

foreach($newhtml->find('table.fpt > td.name') as $price){
echo $price=$price->innertext;
    }
}
```

but the $price is empty.. The strange thing is that if I change the code to this:

```
$newhtml = new simple_html_dom();

$newhtml->load_file('https://www.computers.com/l_bg/?m=7&i=587609');
foreach($newhtml->find('table.fpt > td.name') as $price){
echo $price=$price->innertext;
}
```

the code works.. Why if I manual put the url it works, but when is in loop it doesn't?
Can you please tell me what is wrong and how to find it?

Comment: Try using the hard-coded link (as in your 2nd example) but put it in a loop that goes through 4-5 times `for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { ... }` to see if it's some kind of timing issue.

Comment: I will test it now but same time to share what else I discovered: if I test the headers here http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php with one of the urls https://www.jarcomputers.com/l_bg/?m=7&i=587609 I am getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request => 
is this connected to this?

Comment: Yes, that could very well be it. Perhaps your jarcomputers.com is not returning the pages consistently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be encoding problem. If the url has & its been transformed to `&amp;` which must be replaced with & in order to work.. Thank you anyway for your help !